# Silent printing in Android Chrome

Tags: android, google-chrome, mobile, printing

In desktop version of Chrome, there is a `kiosk` mode that allow background printing without the popup. How to do this in Android?

Comment: There is a service called Scalefusion which allows you to set your android device kiosk mode. More info can be found here: https://blog.scalefusion.com/set-up-chrome-browser-in-kiosk-mode-on-android/

Comment: Why not put that as an answer, instead of a comment, Marc?